# how to reproduce password hash from password

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, password

I need to write php script to convert password value to password hash value.

for example convert the below password into password hash as per magento 2 format.

```
qwer@123 -> b3ef5674b8ae2a4ce0cefb10671fb5b2546475b020548275cad2ea070f2d435c:pQJccCQInyMFaDzVyqCbYCGE56o6avDo:1
```

any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi you can try my code

```
$pwdObj = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface');
$string = 'qwer@123';
echo $pwdObj->getHash($string,true);
```

Comment: It does the job and answers the question @RamaChandranM

Comment: your answer is correct but please try to use without object manager. object manager is not good coding standard. :). and happy and wlcome to contribute MSE

Comment: @RamaChandranM, then how else should we do it?

Answer (score 0):

**My Try**

**Custom Controller To Print Password Hash:**

for testing I alter protected method to public, **createPasswordHash** in Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement

```
<?php


namespace Vendor\Helloworld\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $_account;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context  $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement $account

    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_account=$account;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Execute view action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $password="qwer@123";
        echo $this->_account->createPasswordHash($password);
        // return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

it produce

```
11461f169755245382777f2cf8fcd344933851f302ad3fe4c225bb77f0988b37:BjBTkXlth0bU3rsLKGqqVRgIdo2sYULI:1
```

when I update newly generated database hash value, it allow to login by password qwer@123.

References: [link1](https://mage2.pro/t/topic/931), [link2](https://mage2.pro/t/topic/930)

If anyone have better answer, please post your answer.

Comment: It is throwing an error when generating the hash. Call to protected method Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement::createPasswordHash()